# How to Create Workflow through apex class?

Tags: apex, rest-api, workflow, metadata-api

Is there any workaround to create Workflow through apex?
I'm trying to use the MetadataService.cls but I am not able to achieve that.

Any help will really helpful for me.

Comment: I see types such as `MetadataService .Workflow` are present. Is a critical class missing or is the problem that you are unfamiliar with `MetadataService`?

Comment: Yes, I have use same wrapper for workflow

Comment: OK then post the code you have written and explain what your specific problem is including exact copies of any error messages.

Comment: @KeithC I have use this link ( https://mylittleedge.wordpress.com/2015/09/08/creating-workflow-rules-using-metadataservice-cls/) to create workflow  and it resolved my issue. Thanks for the responce.

Comment: That's good. You could add an answer yourself to your question including that link and a few of the critical snippets of code.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create Workflows in Apex, or more generally make changes to the metadata of your organization, without connecting to the Metadata or Tooling APIs. Both of these APIs involve making a callout and fulfilling various other requirements.

`MetadataService.cls` is part of the popular [`apex-mdapi`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) library, which provides Apex bindings to the Metadata API.

While small portions of the Metadata API are now available in native Apex, creation of Workflows is not among them. At present, you can only work with Page Layouts and Custom Metadata Type records.